# getting Mysql server has gone away error

Tags: php, mysql, web-hosting

I moved my hosting site three weeks ago after that I am start getting below error:

Fatal error: MySQL server has gone away in /home/eprep/public_html/pharmacyprep.com/store/lib/framework/BaseDAO.class.php on line 74

This error is coming when user clicks on submit the order. all the entries are going fine to database for new order but this error is coming instad of showing the order receipt. All other things arw working fine.

Comment: Are you writing something large to the DB?

Comment: And can you post your code? Is hard to know what the problem is just by guessing ;)

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Away, obviously. The question is, why's the bloody thing forgotten what it's supposed to be doing and wandered off to chase butterflies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"MySQL server has gone away" is a MySQL client library error message indicating that the connection to the MySQL server has been lost. Assuming you haven't changed the code in question since before the hosting move, and also that your MySQL database is provided by the same company that hosts your website, I would advise contacting the support department at your new hosting firm and asking them why their database server can't seem to maintain a connection.